# Access an array inside an object using Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Please see the JSON below, which I have validated using https://jsonlint.com/:

```
{
        "People": {
            "data": [{
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "Bert"
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "name": "Brian"
                },
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "name": "Maria"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

I am trying to deserialize this JSON into a class like this:

```
 public class Person
    {
        public string id;
        public string name
    }
```

So far I have tried this:

```
public static List<Person> DeserializePeople(string json)
        {
            var jo = JObject.Parse(json);
            return jo["data"]["People"]
                .Select(s => new Person
                {
                    id = ((string)s[0] == null) ? "" : (string)s[0],
                    name = ((string)s[1] == null) ? "" : (string)s[1],
                })
                .ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var jsonDeserialized= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json); 

List<Person> persons=jsonDeserialized.People.Persons;
```

or just in one line if you only need  a list of persons

```
List<Person> persons = jsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json).People.Persons;
```

output

```
    1   Bert
    2   Brian
    3   Maria
```

classes , you need to use getter /setter

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class People
{ 
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public People People { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is the error I get with the above: "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Person' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"...

Comment: @w0051977  your classes are having bugs, use my classess to avoid the error

Comment: Ignore my last comment.  Your code works - thanks.  +1 for the comprehensive answer.

Comment: @w0051977 You are very welcome